# Logging in should log in on the entire SE, not only one of them

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login

One thing I really hate on SE is that, when I want to ask a question about something, and it gets, lets say, moved to another site, I have to click log-in again and enter my open-id again. Can't you guys just make it so that, whenever I login to lets say, SO, I am automatically logged in to the other SE sites (with the associated accounts) by using a cross-domain cookie. This has several advantages:

- Faster
- Less HTTP Requests
- Less human life-time and energy wasted (better for the environment)

It has only one disadvantage (if it is one at all):

- Stimulates lazyness

Comment: laziness is a virtue, not a vice!

Comment: i can't parse that last link.  what is it?

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, but I don't see the advantage over http://passport.net which works with any site.

Comment: All this trouble you're going through sounds like a mild punishment for asking a question on the wrong site... (And as for the pentrilogy: SOFU, Meta, stackapps.com, Area51: sounds like hexa then?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it'd be great if you could, I don't think you can do this with Open ID unfortunately, as it's controlling the authentication and it does so against a specific domain.

I was pretty sure I'd seen this discussed before & came across [a dup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24446/if-my-accounts-are-linked-across-the-trilogy-why-wont-it-just-log-me-in-to-all), where Jeff interestingly said:

> Beyond that, we are looking at centralized auth for some.. er..
>   future.. stuff we're doing, and I did register http://stackauth.com for that
>   general purpose.

I guess we'll have to wait & see what comes out of that...

Comment: Well, SO, MSO, SU and SF use cookies to check if you are logged in right? I can now sign out of Gmail, but still be logged in on the entire quadrilogy.

Comment: @Koning: Right. Because there's five independent cookies involved, so signing out of Gmail only kills the gmail cookie, not the SOFU ones.

Comment: yep, so what I want is that the 4 `/[SO|MSO|SU|SF]/i` cookies become one, cross-domain cookie.

Answer (score 0):

> log in to FB to see the comments on the newest post.

Maybe *Teh Facebooks* should implement universal login, then!

Comment: And you should implement a feature called Facebook Connect ;)

Comment: @koning that's not universal login, that's "my way or the highway" login..